# IIF Function doesn't produce expected results

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rdlc

I am trying to make `iif` conditional with 2 ReportItems, but there is error in expression below :

```
= IIf((ReportItems!Rate.Value like "0*"), Sum(ReportItems!Amount.Value), Nothing)
```

Comment: Will be helpful if you share what is the error you receive

Comment: here the error output : The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox1.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ refers to more than one report item.  An expression in a page header or footer can refer to only one report item.

Comment: what do you mean by iif??

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: vivek, I have 2 colom data. which is rate and amount. and i want to make sum of amount base on rate in footer. i meant, i want to count the amount value if rate value like "0*"

Comment: i(ReportItems[Rate].Value ==  "0*" ? Sum(ReportItems[Amount].Value) : Nothing;

Comment: it still error vivek.

Comment: \The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox157.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains a colon or a line terminator.  Colons and line terminators are not valid in expressions.

Comment: Don't use `IIF` - this is for backwards compatibility to VB6. From MSDN: Visual Basic 2008 introduces a new If operator that uses short-circuit evaluation. For more information, see If Operator.

Comment: wrong tags, bad title